# How to evaluate empty string and value without compare?

Tags: sql, sql-server

@myvar is an nvarchar(30). How can I do the following evaluation without using an OR?

```
@myvar = '' OR (table1.col1 like @myvar)
```

Is there some other way that is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
(table1.col1 like ISNULL(@myvar,table1.col1))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways, in fact there are many.  However, the form you have performs the best for most versions of SQL Server 2005 onwards if you add OPTION (RECOMPILE).

Look here for the definitive guide to [searching with dynamic conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).  Follow the link for your version of SQL Server.

Comment: Recompile certainly helped but the compared execution plans are the same.  Shouldn't there be some difference in these?

Comment: Have you read the entire article, which is the bible on dynamic searching?

Answer (score 1):

```
table1.col1 like ISNULL(NULLIF(@myvar, ''), table1.col1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If one had an interview question where `OR` was forbidden and [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) were forgotten then one might use:

```
case
  when @myvar = '' then 42
  when table1.col1 like @myvar then 666
  else 0 end > 0
```

One might also experiment with `Len( @myvar ) = 0`.